# Set default "Manage Stock?" to "yes" when a new variation is created (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'd like "Manage Stock" get checked by default in woocommerce JUST as soon as creating a new variation ( a child is added to .woocommerce_variations.wc-metaboxes.ui-sortable) but my code doesn't worth

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_admin_product_variations_js' );

function custom_admin_product_variations_js() {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'product' === $post_type ) :
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        // Function to handle changes in the DOM
        function handleDOMChanges(mutationsList, observer) {
            $('#variable_product_options').on('change', function () {
                $('input.variable_manage_stock').each(function () {
                    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').closest('div').find('.wc_input_stock').val(1);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // Create a MutationObserver
        const targetNode = document.querySelector('.woocommerce_variations.wc-metaboxes.ui-sortable');
        const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

        const observer = new MutationObserver(handleDOMChanges);

        // Start observing changes in the DOM
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    });
    </script><?php
    endif;
}
```

I've already tried all posts in stackoverflow regarding this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that i have tested and works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function observeVariationChanges() {
        var variationContainer = $('.woocommerce_variations.wc-metaboxes.ui-sortable');

        if (variationContainer.length) {
            $('.variable_manage_stock').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $('.show_if_variation_manage_stock').show();
        }
    }

    // Use a MutationObserver to detect DOM changes
    var observer = new MutationObserver(observeVariationChanges);

    // Start observing changes
    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
});
```